# Read headers, CURL

Tags: c++, c, curl, libcurl

is there a way to read the html headers from a curl perform reply?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Take a look at [this example](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/sepheaders.html). It's exactly what you want.

Comment: the link is broken :(